# Callouts/annotation showing in map layout but not in map canvas

Tags: qgis-3, print-composer, mapcanvas, callout

I need to modify a map layout to remove a couple of callouts. They appear in the Layout but are not showing in the main canvas. I'm not sure who or how they were created. Any ideas on what's going on and how I can edit them? Screenshot attached to show how these callouts appear in the map layout, if that is of any help.

Using QGIS 3.30.2-Hertogenbosch

[image]

Comment: Would you also please share a screenshot of how they look like on the Print Composer? Also, it would be helpful to share the settings of those callouts/annotations.

Comment: The attached screenshot is the view on the Print Composer. They are not showing in the map canvas - I can't access the settings because I can't find them